# Azure Digital Twins <---> The Things Network (2 way communication)

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-digital-twins, ttn

I am working on a project that requires two-way communication between Azure Digital twins and the Things Network. Right now I am able to connect my AZDT to the TTN via an IoT HUB to update the twin with "read variables" for example I have a CO2 sensor that sends data via the IoT HUB instance to the AZDT.
However I am not sure how to do the communication the other way around, when I send a signal to a "write" variable, and this message is carried over to the device, for example I have a smart plug that can be turned off via the AZDT.

anyone could give me some ideas? or support on that?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you check out the TTI IoT Hub integration documentation page?

There is a section that explains `Desired Properties` for updating values *between The Things Stack and IoT Hub*
https://www.thethingsindustries.com/docs/integrations/cloud-integrations/azure-iot-hub/device-twin/#desired-properties

To generate a downlink you need to update the shadow of the device and save it, which will schedule a downlink for the device on The Things Stack.

To trigger this from the twin itself, you need to update the Digital Twin state that contains the property of the device in question
I would take a look at additional docs from MSFT on this
e.g.,

- Updating device twin in IoT Hub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins
- Updating Digital Twin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-manage-twin#update-a-digital-twin

Hope this helps